# Sequelize Authentication cannot complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm starting out with node.js and sequelize and I get the following error:

```
/home/cbaket/test/test.js:9
    .complete(function(err) {
     ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cbaket/test/test.js:9:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

My file: test.js is:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('apidb', 'apidb', 'apidb', {
    dialect: "mysql", // or 'sqlite', mysql', 'mariadb'
    port:    3306 // or 5432 (for postgres)
});

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .complete(function(err) {
        if (!!err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
        } else {
            console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
        }
    });
```

I'm following one of the early tutorials on the Sequelieze website.

I installed the latest sequelize and mysql with the following command.

```
$ npm install mysql  
$ npm install sequelize
```

I have tried a lot of similar examples and always get the same error.
The libraries are working because other examples work fine, i could create tables in the database and get data from it but the authenticate function always fails.

Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 21):

Authenticate returns a Promise in the later versions of sequelize:
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/2.0/lib/sequelize.js#L939

Read the bluebird documentation here as it is quite useful:
https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md

Something like this should work (make sure you check for connection errors...this is just a simple example):

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sql = new Sequelize('DB', 'UNAME', 'PASS', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

var test = sql.authenticate()
    .then(function () {
        console.log("CONNECTED! ");
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("SOMETHING DONE GOOFED");
    })
    .done();
```

Comment: You have the correct answer. So +1. However, you don't need to assign the authentication to a var the way you do with var test = sql.authenticate()... you could just use sql.authenticate()...

Answer (score 4):

Hi sequelize changed their auth scheme in latest release.. Please revert back to older version and try it

Comment: So how do i test connection in new sequelize version??
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you were right!! ;)
I just remove sequelize and then reinstall an old veriosn:

> npm install sequelize@1.7.0

and it works!!

I didn't found any info about that... Shouldn't they warn users from deprecated or modified functions ?¿?...

THANKS!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're looking for

```
Sequelize.authenticate().complete(...)
```

instead of

```
Sequelize.authenticate.complete(...)
```

Sequelize.authenticate is a function that returns a promise. It's not an object with a .complete() method. If you don't execute it, no promise will be returned. If no promise is returned, you can't run .complete() on the promise.

Hope this helps you out.

Here is some documentation on [Promises from the Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: thanks for answering so fast! ;) 
I just tried it but it didn't work :(
and i found other examples with same syntax : `sequelize.authenticata().complete(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the sequelize module which is installed in your system and install this version using

npm install sequelize@1.7.0

Check the models folder and make sure it contains proper files